# Past participle or present participle

Tags: nouns, gerunds, participles

> "I wrote Shapiro a letter *congratulating* him on *having won* a
> race."

Is the word *congratulating* a present participle? And *having won* a gerund?

Comment: Yes, at least in trad grammar, though it's just "having" (not "having won") that is a gerund. But the distinction is pointless, since they are both verbs, and some modern grammars simply call them 'gerund-participles'. How sensible is that!

Comment: What about "congratulating" is it a present participle or gerund in the sentence? It seems to qualify the noun complement "a letter".

Comment: Yes, it is a present participle (or in my grammar a 'gerund-participle'). And, yes, the clause "congratulating him on having won the race" modifies the noun "letter". It has the same meaning as the relative clause in "a letter that/which congratulated him on having won a race".